# OpenGL pixels drawn with each horizontal pair swapped

Tags: opengl, distortion, pixelformat

I'm somewhat new to OpenGL though I'm fairly sure my problem lies in the pixel format being used, or how my texture is being generated...

I'm drawing a texture onto a flat 2D quad using a 16bit RGB5_A1 pixel format, though I don't make use of any alpha at this stage.  The problem I'm having is that each pair of horizontal pixel values have been *swapped*.

That is... if the pixels positions should be in this order (assume 8x2 image)

```
0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 7
```

they are instead drawn as

```
1 0 3 2
5 4 7 6
```

Or, more clearly from this image (below).
Left is what I get... Right is what I should get.

[image].

The question is... How have I ended up with this? Is there something wrong with the pixel format? Unlikely since the colours all appear correct, and I would expect all kinds of nasty if it were down to endian-ness. Suggestions greatly appreciated.

**Update**: Turns out the problem was in my source renderer. Interestingly, I've avoided the problem entirely by using 32-bit textures (haven't tried 24-bit at this point).

Comment: I'd rather suspect the texture input data format. What does your glTexture2D call look like ?

Comment: Looks like an endianess problem to me. Am I right assuming, that you're either using a 16 bit type for the data points, read from a file in 16 bit blocks or have the texture data specified as a hard coded array on a 16 bit type? To avoid any troubles with endianess you should always store and process I/O data as arrays of the smallest type that can hold the building blocks of the data (usually bytes). CHAR_BITS tells you, how many bits there are to a char, but it's asserted to be at least 8.

Comment: Can you post a minimal GLUT program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hmm. Datenwolf, thanks for the tip about endianness. I've determined that the problem lies in the generation of the source texture - when I clobber the texture with hardcoded data it renders as it should. A completely hacky solution (swapping each pixel immediately prior to glTexSubImage2D) achieves the desired display, though I'm fairly sure it will kill performance.  Thanks for all your responses.  Now I just need to work out why the input format is busted (Bahbar, seems you were on the money).

Answer (score -1):

This may be unrelated, and you have found a workaround, but it could be related to OpenGL unpack alignment. Have you tried with the following call ? To instruct the alignment of every image row to 1 byte (default is 4).

`glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);`

Comment: That would result in skewed output, not in interleaved pixels.