# OpenGL horizontal pixel pairs drawn swapped

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, distortion

I have problem that is extremely similar to the one described in [OpenGL pixels drawn with each horizontal pair swapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666202/opengl-pixels-drawn-with-each-horizontal-pair-swapped). The main difference is that I'm getting this disortion even when I feed the texture one-byte red-only values.

**EDIT**: By closer inspection of normal textures, I have discovered that this problem manifests when rendering any 2D texture. I tried rotating the resulting texture by swapping the texture coordinates. The resulting picture still have swapped *visual* horizontal pixels - so I'm assuming that the data in the texture is good, and the disortion occurs when rendering the texture.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

C++:

```
struct coord_t { float x; float y; }

GLint loc = glGetAttributeLocation(program, "coord");
if (loc != -1) {
  glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
    sizeof(coord_t), static_cast<void *>(offsetof(coord_t, x)));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);
}
loc = glGetAttributeLocation(program, "tex_coord");
if (loc != -1) {
  glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(coord_t),
    static_cast<void *>((void*)(4*sizeof(coord_t)+offsetof(coord_t, x)));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);
}

// ... Texture binding to GL_TEXTURE_2D ...

coord_t pos[] = {coord_t{-1.f,-1.f}, coord_t{1.f,-1.f}
  coord_t{-1.f,1.f}, coord_t{1.f,1.f}
};

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(pos), pos); // position
glBuffefSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pos), sizeof(pos), pos); // texture coordinates

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Corresponding vertex shader:

```
#version 110
attribute vec2 coord;
attribute vec2 tex_coord;
varying vec2 tex_out;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(coord.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
  tex_out = tex_coord;
}
```

Corresponding fragment shader:

```
#version 110
uniform sampler2D my_texture;
varying vec2 tex_out;

void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = texture(my_texture, tex_out);
}
```

Comment: It is totally unclear what is going on. You should provide more context. It might as well be your drawing code which is wrong, or your subimg data not what you expect. Or both. Reading the texture data back (or inspecting it in a gl debugger) might also be a good idea.

Comment: You're correct that endianness wouldn't be an issue, but alignment might depending on the value of `width`. You've already compensated for that with the unpack alignment setting. Reading the data back using this format could be an issue, that's affected by pack alignment (default is also 4).

Comment: Thanks for both previous comments.

I expanded the question with new findings and samples from my actual code, that I think are relevant. But as I'm new to OpenGL, I probably elipsised something important and I will be glad to expand it again, if pointed to it.

Comment: You are loading the texture incorrectly. Most probably loading it as 24-bit instead of 32-bit. Can you share more code on your texture loading? You should check your texture format, too. Is it RGB, is it RGBA, is it ABGR, etc? You should check the stride that goes with your texture loading. If texture is RGB24, use stride of 3. If it is RGBA32 use 4, etc.

Comment: @DimoMarkov I'm aware that this can be an issue, but as specified in the first paragraph, I'm loading the data using combination of GL_RED and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE - which means one byte at a time, with stride of 1.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive code investigation, I managed to find the culprit.

**I was setting the blending function incorrectly, using `GL_SRC1_ALPHA` and `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC1_ALPHA` instead of `GL_SRC_ALPHA` and `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`.**

Comment: I'm aware that the code and other details in the question are irrelevant to the this answer. Before marking this answer as solution, I would like to ask if I should update/abridge the question, or leave it as it is (I cannot ask in meta, not enough reputation).